# Routing instead of NAT/Masquerade for WiFi Tether clients

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, networking, router

When clients connect to Android Tethering they get IPs of the private Tethering networl. There is plenty of info available on how to NAT/Masquerade WiFi tethering clients (for example into a VPN), but I haven't managed to find how should I change or re-write IPTABLES and ROUTES in order to avoid natting/masquerading and just make ordinary routing from the tethered devices IP to the other networks (or a VPN).

Example:
Local Tether client 1 gets : 192.168.43.1/24
Local Tether client 2 gets : 192.168.43.2/24 ...
and at the VPN interface we have the 10.1.0.0/24 Network.
Disabling NAT and adding the routes in an ordinary router is easy, but I need help to do it on my Android device.
Thank you!